# Send variable from the form (POST) via ajax to another PHP script (GET)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

For last couple days I've tried to find proper upload script for my files. When I found one I've noticed that I could use couple more features for it. In this script there is a simple form with just "Browse" button, progress bar (Ajax, jQuery/JS) and the Upload button. That's it. What I'm trying to do is to add some features to the form, like choosing category of the file. So here's the code for **upload_form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */
/* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and for **file_upload_parser.php**

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test_uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

What I want to do is add some more options to the form (like **"select"**) and after pressing the Upload button, send the variable from that form to the .php file and use GET function to get that variable so I can use it for something else, like add that file and its category to the database. The problem is I don't know how to do this. I've tried to change the Upload button for submit-type, but it's not working (bad idea, now I know), I've tried to add some variables into the JS code, but (in my case) it's not working as well. Can you please help me solve this problem? 
I will be very grateful for any help I can get.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` parameters must be added to the URL. So if the form contains

```
<select id="menu">
    ...
</select>
```

your Javascript would be:

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var menuValue = _("menu").value;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php?menu=" + menuValue);
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

Then your PHP can use `$_GET['menu']` to get the value of this parameter.

BTW, you need to change your `onclick` to `onclick="uploadFile(); return false;"`. It has to return false to prevent the default form submission.

Comment: I've tried your method and when I'm using $_GET like this: `$dest = $_GET['send'];` then the value for `$dest` is **null**. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You used `?send=` in the URL?

Comment: Yes. Code with var:
`var dest = _("cat".value)`
and my link:
`ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php?send=" + dest`, also my **select** looks like this: `<select id="cat" name="cat">`.

Comment: It should be `_("cat").value` not `_("cat".value)`

Comment: Heh, it's working like a charm now :) Thank you very much and sorry for my silly mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute one more ajax call after completion of file upload. Like,

```
function completeHandler(event){
        _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
        _("progressBar").value = 0;
        sendSelectedParameter();
}
function sendSelectedParameter(){
    //get selected value and execute another ajax call of GET type.
}
```