# How to pass form inputs via ajax to other php file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I found this ajax file upload code on github, its working as i wanted but i want to pass more varibales from my form inputs via ajax. i have followed a question on stackoverflow - [Send variable from the form (POST) via ajax to another PHP script (GET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166416/send-variable-from-the-form-post-via-ajax-to-another-php-script-get) . but in my case its not working, i am not getting value via GET on upload.php page.
here is the javascript code

```
<script>

function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var appid = _("appid").value;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "modules/upload/demo5/upload.php?appid="+appid);
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
```

this is the form area

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                             <input type="hidden" name="appid" id="appid" value="EVSA75883664">
                             <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
                             <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile(); return false;"><br><br>
                             <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
                              <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
                             <h3 id="status"></h3>

                     </form>
```

and this is upload.php page code

```
    <?php

include('../../connect.php');

$appid = $_GET['appid'];

$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test_uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "$fileName is Uploaded Successfully. <br><br> <a href='https://www.indian-evisas.org.in/uploadppt.php?appid='.$appid.'>Click here to Proceed to Next Step</a>";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}


?>
```

Comment: Don't append just the file manually to the formData object, but pass the form itself to its constructor instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData (And then access `appid` & co. via `$_POST`, corresponding to the method of your form.)

Comment: @CBroe - I followed the link and going to check with post method, but whats wrong with this code. can you correct it where is error.